# how to get IIS 6 to parse a .html page as ASP

Tags: redirect, asp-classic, iis-6

I have a site with several .html pages which are to be changed to ASP pages. I want to create a 301 redirect from each old .html page to the new .asp page and the site is on IIS 6.

I think the only solution with windows would be to add all redirects within IIS but it is time consuming as there is lots of pages and I am on a shared server so the host won't do it.

Another idea would be to have IIS interpret the .html files as ASP, I could then add ASP tags to each page to create the redirect. The host would be OK to do this for as long as it does not affect other sites and does not take long to do. Is this possible and how?
Unless there is a solution faster to add the 301 redirects, I have no problem doing the work myself for as long it is fast for them to do.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open IIS
2. Select your Website
3. Press Right Click Mouse Button & click on Properties
4. Select Home Directory Tab & click on Configuration Button
5. In Application Mapping & If .html Extension is their & select it & click edit button
6. In Edit Dialog Box In Executable text box add 'C:\WINNT\System32\inetsrv\asp.dll' or path to asp.dll & press ok...

Your done with this now your .html page will process the asp code...

Comment: Yes I think I just did by clicking yes on "was this post useful to you", is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

For redirecting you can use clientside script like Javascript or yor can use server side script like classic asp. But you need to change the extension of your page. So you can use this script to your page

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
window.location="http://yourLocation";
</script>
```

when you go to your page this will redirect to the location you mentioned here. You can test with `window.location="http://www.google.com";` for now.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do a mass redirect using ASP classic on IIS6 is to set your 404 error page to an ASP file. That file then uses logic to redirect a .html file to the .asp equivalent. This is a very efficient and powerful way of handling redirects on II6 without having to modify server settings or configurations (well, other than just the initial custom error page).

Please note you should also set your 500 server errors to use the same ASP page. This way it can also deal with "Directory listing denied" on virtual directories and know how to redirect them (or just display a 404).